# USB stick not usable after ISO boot burn

Tags: boot, usb

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and have made 2 ISO boot sticks, one for Mint 17.1 and the other for 14.04. The Mint USB was made using 'Startup Disc Creator' from the software centre and the Ubuntu one was from Unetbootin, also from software centre.
Both worked fine and I have both installed, no problem.

However, now the USB's both have problems, The mint one is visible
 on the files menu but says that it only has 1gb of space (it did have 8) and the Ubuntu one isn't visible at all when I plug it in.

Now here's the biggest hurdle :)   I've been using Linux distros for about 3 years now so am ok with documents, games, internet, thunderbird and so on, but after attempting to grind my way unsuccessfully through various issues  over many hours back then I adopted a policy of 'back up and reboot'  (20 mins to sort any problem) In short I don't understand most technical jargon.

Is there a way i can 'reset' the usbs? as I have attempted a bit of DIY correcting and neither of them even boot now :(

Cheers

Graham

Answer (score 2):

Install a partition editor, such as GParted, from software center or command line:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Now, open GParted. It will look something like this:

[image]

At the top right dropdown menu, select your USB stick. If you don't know which your USB stick is: Use the disk size as an orientation. Also, the stick will most likely be FAT32-formatted.

After you are totally sure that you found the right disk, unmount each available partition (indicated by a lock sign next to the partition name in GParted, with my icon theme it looks like a safe door...) by right clicking them and selecting *Unmount*.

After all partitions on the USB are unmounted, and you are still sure that you're operating on the correct drive, select

*Device* → *Create Partition Table...*

Read the warning carefully, select `msdos` and click OK. After the new partition table is created, you should see something like this:

[image]

Now, right click on the unallocated space, and select *New*. You'll then see a dialog in which you can set up the new partition. Leave everything as it is, only set the file system to *FAT32* You may also label the partition, if you like:

[image]

Click OK. Now, this action will not be executed automatically. To apply this, click the Apply button in the main window. Yours may look like a tick instead. It may take a short time to complete.

After you are done, simply close GParted, unplug the USB and replug it and you are done.